# use css variable with scss darken and ligthen filter

Tags: css, sass

I would like to use scss `lighten()` and `darken()` function with CSS4 `var`.

Like this :

```
box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 50px 45px darken(var(--colorbtn),20%);
```

It seems not working, gulp write this:

```
Error: $color: "var(--colorbtn)" is not a color for `darken'
```

Its not possible to do that?

Comment: Perhaps give this a read http://codepen.io/jakealbaugh/post/css4-variables-and-sass

Comment: Custom properties are not "CSS4". What even is CSS4 anyway? (It doesn't actually exist, but I'm wondering what other people think it is.)

Comment: Usually people think CSS4 exists because they saw a level 4 module. But CSS variables are level 1. What makes you think they are CSS4?

Comment: you're right, it's not css4 the title is wrong, i didn't know that css var existed already. We can define the level 4 maybe by the new selector levels https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This can't really work because SASS is a *preprocessor*, and CSS custom properties can be dynamically changed at *run-time*.  For SASS to be able to preprocess this with darken, it would have to replace the custom property with a static value, in which case the usefulness of the custom property is lost.