# Setting SASS variable to CSS3 variable causes error in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, angular, sass, bootstrap-4

## [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scss-demo-x935ev) link

For some reason when setting Bootstrap variables to a CSS3 variables my Angular 6 app breaks with the following error

[image]

This is indeed the first usage of the SCSS variable in the bootstrap file, so it is obviously not happy with how I am setting it. I have made a very simple [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scss-demo-x935ev) to replicate the issue. Have a look at the styles.scss.

Essentially this is what produces this error.

**styles.scss**

```
:root{
  --primary: #0f0;
}

$primary: var(--primary); // Broken
// $primary: #f00;  // Working

@import '../bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Any ideas on why Bootstrap may not be happy with this?

Comment: try `map-get` to achieve this

Comment: it's actually css3 vars;)

Comment: Any chance you could provide an example? Will mess around a bit now. Thanks.

Comment: And what is the purpose of this? since you have a CSS variable why introducing a SCSS variable?

Comment: Trying to use angular fileReplacment to dynamically change the theme depending on the environment. And bootswatch needs these SCSS variables. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184282/angular-dynamically-swap-sass-styles-depending-on-environment

Comment: It doesn't work because --primary is a CSS variable, not a SASS variable. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45496360/using-css-variables-as-sass-function-arguments

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

It appears you cannot use css variables within SASS functions due to the dynamic nature of css variables together with the fact that sass is a preprocessor.

See this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655500/use-css-variable-with-scss-darken-and-ligthen-filter) for a more detailed explanation.